# I want when "C-w" is pressed, execute delete-backward-char when no region is selected and kill-region when the region is selected

Tags: key-bindings, region, words, deletion

Similarly, I want to delete word backward when `C-u C-w` is pressed.

I would also value recommendation on cut/paste/kill conventions.

I tried to bind `C-w` to delete-backward-char, but kill-region stopped working.
Please help as I find it irritating to stretch my fingers to tap DEL key and I commit a lot of mistakes while typing.
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking you at your word, that you want to delete, and not kill, for the char and word cases, try this.

(Killing is like "cut" - it not only deletes the text but puts it on the `kill-ring`, which means it's available for yanking ("pasting"). Just deleting does not make the deleted text available for yanking.)

But if backward *killing* words is OK, then you don't need `my-backward-delete-word` - just use `backward-kill-word` in its place.

```lisp
(defun my-C-w-dwim (&optional arg)
  "`delete-backward-char`, but if region is active then kill region.
With prefix arg N, delete backward to the start of the Nth word."
  (interactive "P")
  (cond (arg
         (my-backward-delete-word (prefix-numeric-value arg)))
        ((use-region-p)
         (kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
        (t (delete-backward-char 1))))
    

(defun my-backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Like `backward-kill-word`, but just delete."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (backward-word arg) (point))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'my-C-w-dwim)
```

Comment: Maybe explain the difference between deleting and killing?

Comment: Good point, @NickD. So: *killing* removes text and places it on the `kill-ring`, ready to *yank*. This is roughly the same as what most apps call cutting and pasting. Deleting just removes text; the only way to get it back is to undo.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read such a big question (for me at least), Your code worked perfectly but the only addition I did was to assign your 'my-backward-delete-word function to 'M-w' to delete word backward. I believe I will be able to understand your code one day.

Comment: @NickD. Done. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and reading this and you just want backwards delete word without the c-u first so it works like the normal linux command line when nothing is highlighted copy this:

```lisp
(defun my-C-w-dwim (&optional arg)
  "`delete-backward-char`, but if region is active then kill region.                                                                      
With prefix arg N, delete backward to the start of the Nth word."
  (interactive "P")
  (cond (arg
         (my-backward-delete-word (prefix-numeric-value arg)))
        ((use-region-p)
         (kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
    (t (my-backward-delete-word (prefix-numeric-value arg)))))


(defun my-backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Like `backward-kill-word`, but just delete."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (backward-word arg) (point))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") 'my-C-w-dwim)
```